# C# remove json child node using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, wpf, json.net

I am developing an app using c# wpf in .net 3.5.
I use newtonsoft library to parse the json string.

I want to know how to remove a child node of json.

For example,
My json data =

```
{"employees":[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}]}
```

The function

```
jobject.Remove("employees");
```

removes all the nodes sucessfully

I would like to know how to remove the first employee detail alone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you parse your json into a `JObject`, the employees property will be a `JArray`. The `JArray` class has methods you're looking for, such as `JArray.RemoveAt`

The following code will do what you want

```
string json =
@"{
    ""employees"":[
        { ""firstName"":""John"", ""lastName"":""Doe""}, 
        { ""firstName"":""Anna"", ""lastName"":""Smith""}, 
        { ""firstName"":""Peter"", ""lastName"":""Jones""}
    ]
}";

dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
(obj.employees as JArray).RemoveAt(0);

// obj now only has "Anna Smith" and "Peter Jones"
```

`dynamic` was introduced in .NET 4.0, so for 3.5 you'd use something like this instead

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
(obj["employees"] as JArray).RemoveAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.SelectToken("Employees")[0].Parent.Remove();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, so the OP and other readers can understand how this works.

Comment: Each element in a JObject has a parent object, that object is the one you remove to remove it's child