# C# JSON.NET remove strings with ","

Tags: c#, json, json.net

My last question to json.net:

My file contains some of those guys here:

```
{
      "type": "06A, 06B, 06C, 06D, 06E",
      "qt": "6-8-",
      "id": "06A, 06B, 06C, 06D, 06E6-8-"
    }
```

Now I want to clean my file and remove all objects where the type contains a comma or ",".

I already read this: [C# remove json child node using newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391303/c-sharp-remove-json-child-node-using-newtonsoft) but there is no possibility to remove the object if it contains a special char...

I would really appreciate any help!

At the moment I have:

```
public void filter()
    {
        string sourcePath = @Settings.Default.folder;
        string pathToSourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, "file.json");

        string list = File.ReadAllText(pathToSourceFile);
        Temp temporaray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Temp>(list);

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by *blocks*? what is the expected output json? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, with "blocks" I mean the whole object containing type, qt and id

Comment: Deserialize into objects and filter with `Where`. Then you can re-serialize to json if you need.

Comment: @SimpleVar now I added some code, how can I filter with "Where"?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than deserializing to a temporary `Temp` type, you can use [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to parse the JSON and remove objects containing a `"type"` property matching your criterion:

```
var root = JToken.Parse(json);

if (root is JContainer)
{
    // If the root token is an array or object (not a primitive)
    var query = from obj in ((JContainer)root).Descendants().OfType<JObject>()  // Iterate through all JSON objects 
                let type = obj["type"] as JValue                                // get the value of the property "type"
                where type != null && type.Type == JTokenType.String 
                    && ((string)type).Contains(",")                             // If the value is a string that contains a comma
                select obj;                                                     // Select the object
    foreach (var obj in query.ToList())
    {
        // Remove the selected object
        obj.Remove();
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oAv7wJ).

Then to serialize to a file with name `fileName`, you can serialize the `root` object as shown in [Serialize JSON to a file](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonSerializerToFile.htm):

```
using (var file = File.CreateText(fileName))
{
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
    serializer.Serialize(file, root);
}
```

Comment: okay, and how do I have to continue after obj.Remove(); ? string gesamt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(@Settings.Default.folder + "\\" + "upload" + "\\" + "ee.json", gesamt); won`t work...

Comment: @Francis try the `root` object. Great answer, only thing I'd change is `.ToArray()` instead of list for "faster iteration ninini"

Comment: @Francis - what do you mean **it doesn't work**?  Are you asking, *how can I write a string to a file?*  Or are you asking, *How can I serialize an object to a file with Json.NET?*  If the latter, see http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonSerializerToFile.htm.